# Android command line build (Mac), no Google APIs

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application which uses Google maps and I can't find maps.jar in my project directory, can't import com.google.android.apps.MapActivity, and so on. The project was originally created without Google APIs, then updated on the command line to change to the correct target. My project.properties file now says this:

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:10
```

...which I presume is correct.
I can see the Google APIs in the sdk.dir ($HOME/bin/android-sdk-mac_x86) but they don't seem to be included in the app. Can anyone suggest as to why this might be?

The reason for developing on the command line is that as a Vim fan I like using Eclim (http://eclim.org/).

Comment: while creating project just choose the android: google api..
they are asking you for the choose API you want to target?

Comment: As far as I am aware I have chosen the correct API, but the relevant files aren't being imported into my project directory.

Comment: please display your whole logcat...

Comment: It is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1623843/logcat.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added this line in your application manifest?

```
<application
    ...
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: I have, and it's within the <application> tags.

Comment: I've now opened the project in Eclipse in the hope that that might help. I can see that (1) the Google APIs are listed in the package explorer under this project, (2) the build target is set to Google APIs 10, and (3) there are red X marks indicating an error with the project, specifically related to a failure to import com.google.android.maps. This seems utterly bizarre.

Comment: where do you have located your google maps jar? For my project (using Eclipse) I had to copy it into the "libs" subdirectory of my project.

Comment: Subsequently, I re-created the project from scratch using Eclipse, setting the correct build target, then added my code back in. It will still not find the Google libraries.

Comment: The Google maps jar is located in $HOME/bin/android-sdk-mac_x86, a location which Eclipse recognises.

Comment: I put the jars to which Eclipse refers into the project's libs directory, with no luck. Ant doesn't seem to be noting that there are external libraries; here's the output of 'ant clean debug': http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1623843/errors.txt

Comment: Finally! There was a small typo in my import statement in the activity file causing this, which I somehow managed to keep missing.